# App to create Flash site demo video?

Tags: flash, video, web, video-capture

Is there a good app to use to quickly create a demo video for a site?  I'd like to show a sample of what's inside the site to throw onto the homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [WINK](http://www.debugmode.com/wink/) very good. However, you can find other, [HERE](http://www.swftools.com/tools-category.php?cat=929).

Comment: I ended up downloading CamStudio from that second link you provided, thanks! http://camstudio.org/

Answer (score 1):

I've used [BB Flashback](http://www.bbsoftware.co.uk/bbflashback.aspx) to make video tutorials and demos.  It works well.

The free version exports to both FLV and SWF.